# Why exactly car tires quality affect braking distance?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, car

It is a known fact that car tires' quality/tread depth directly affect the braking distance. I am a little confused about the exact reasons. I can understand how tires with worse quality can lose traction completely and start skidding, but if the contact is maintained, where is the difference coming from? Can tires skid a little and then recover traction (then this intermittent skidding would make the difference in the braking distance)?

Thank you.

Comment: The material quality and tread design affect the static and dynamic friction. Once a tire starts skidding that means the maximum force of static friction has been overcome. Once that happens the force of dynamic friction begins and this is usually less than the static friction. That's why when you brake you don't want your tires to skid if you can help it. The only way a skidding tire will "recover" is if you ease off the brakes to allow the wheel to roll enough so that the force of static friction falls below the current dynamic friction, so intermittent skidding won't happen without input.

Answer (score 1):

"It is a known fact that car tires' quality/tread depth directly affect the braking distance"
Well, sort of. The 'quality' of the tire affects the dry braking distance, the tread depth/design and the 'quality' (to a much lesser extent) of the tire affect wet braking. Dry braking is pretty much a function of the compound, tire width, and inflation pressure. Tread doesn't come into it significantly (there are ifs and buts). Wet braking is largely a case of pumping water away from the contact patch, hence the importance of pressure and tread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I understand correctly that when a car brakes on a dry or a wet road, and braking is well bellow the "Threshold braking" limit/skidding, the thread depth, air pressure or overall tire quality will not make a difference on breaking distance ? And thread is mostly needed to maintain contact (prevent skidding) in harsh conditions and probably give more kinetic friction if skidding happened?

Comment: There would still be a difference in dry braking distance for a given pedal force for different tire constructions, but I haven't directly seen figures for that. The analagous situation is cornering, which uses many of the same mechanisms, and there, even at small slip angles, tire pressure and tire construction have a noticeable and measurable effect.  So far as I know the grooves are there for wet weather and I suppose snow, but I've never been involved with them.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for - "dry braking distance for a given pedal force", and it it surprisingly difficult to find information about this online. Found more or less what I was looking for in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsnYqCRWTbE . So, there is always some sliding present, even on dry roads.

Comment: Here's a nice chart showing tread depth and water depth. https://www.euromotor.org/mod/resource/view.php?id=21456

Answer (score 0):

One of the factors in a good quality tire is that its shear module is low.

if we notice the graph of shear resistance versus applied force:

.

.

[image: shear res]

We realize a lower shear modulus allows the tread of the tire to slide more adding to the threshold of motion before the tire skids.

Assuming the momentum $P_{normal}= mv-mo$ used to get to the threshold of motion for a normal tire

$$P_{quality-tire}>P_{normal-tire}, \therefore mv_2>mv_1  $$
$$v_2>v_1$$

So the car will not skid until higher speeds.

And even in case of a rare emergency stop, after skidding the tire because of the build-in design to generate a lot of surface heat the tire will burn a thin film on the surface turning it to a sticky surface with a higher index of friction.